# How to treat warnings as errors in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How make `cargo build` treat warnings as fatal errors? I am looking for option that is commonly named `-Werror` in other languages.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/8oz7md/make_cargo_fail_on_warning/

Comment: Hi there! I think your question is answered by the linked Q&A. If that is not the case, just tell us here in the comments so that your question can be reopened! In short: `--deny warnings` as `rustc` flag (or via `RUSTFLAGS="--deny warnings"`) or `#![deny(warnings)]` as crate attribute.